# Using nested For Loops to create a table of numbers and stars

Tags: java, for-loop, nested

I need to print a table that looks like this if the user entered a 5 using nested for loops:

```
****5
***45
**345
*2345
12345
```

I've been working on this for hours and the closest I got was:

```
int size = scan.nextInt();
    for (int i = 1; i <= size; i++)
      {
         for (int star = size-1; star >= i; star--) 
             System.out.print("*");

         for (int k = 1; k <= i; k++) 
             System.out.print(i);

         System.out.println(); 
         }
```

Which outputs this:

```
****1
***12
**123
*1234
12345
```

Answer (score 0):

You have too many loops; I find it easier to reason about zero based looping so I'm going to use that. Iterate `i` and `j` from `0` to `size`. If `j + 1` is greater than `size - i - 1` then we want to print `j + 1`. Otherwise, we want a star. Like,

```
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
        if (j + 1 > size - i - 1) {
            System.out.print(j + 1);
        } else {
            System.out.print('*');
        }
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

For `size = 5` that outputs (as requested)

```
****5
***45
**345
*2345
12345
```

If you *simply* must have one based indices, that would be

```
for (int i = 1; i <= size; i++) {
    for (int j = 1; j <= size; j++) {
        if (j > size - i) {
            System.out.print(j);
        } else {
            System.out.print('*');
        }
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep your loops and avoid if statements, you can tweak last loop by changing

```
for (int k = 1; k <= i; k++)
```

into

```
for (int k = 1+size-i; k <= size; k++)
```

Btw I also find it way easier to start loops from 0, so updated code would look like this:

```
int size = scan.nextInt();
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        for (int star = size-1; star > i; star--)
            System.out.print("*");

        for (int k = size-i; k <= size; k++)
            System.out.print(k);

        System.out.println();
    }
```

I hope it helps